# Angular 2 - Error Invalid provider unit test

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, typescript

I'm working on a project with Angular 2 RC4 generate by Angular-Cli, and i have the same error on each of my unit test.

> Error: Invalid provider - only instances of Provider and Type are
>   allowed, got: [object Object] (line 170)

Here is a simple example of one spec :

```
import {addProviders,inject} from "@angular/core/testing";
import {AppComponent} from "./app.component";

beforeEach(() => {
  addProviders([AppComponent])
});

describe('Component : App', () => {
  it('should created an instance',
    inject([AppComponent], (app:AppComponent) => {
      expect(app).toBeTruthy();
    }));

});
```

This error appears on each spec which need providers.

Here is the component of app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import  { EnvComponent } from "./env/env.component"

// Routage
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.css'],
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, EnvComponent],
})


export class AppComponent {

}
```

PS :  The tests worked correctly in Angular 2 RC3

Answer (score 1):

You need to only use providers or types as parameters of the `addProviders` method:

```
addProviders([AppComponent])
```

It seems that `AppComponent` isn't a class... What is the content of the `app.component` module?

Comment: In RC3 the tests were made with beforeEachProviders(), now it's deprecated.